# How to get the closest table after form is submitted via jquery using ajaxform

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have this structure

```
<table> <tr><td><form>   .........<input type="submit"/> </form> </td></tr></table>
```

I am submitting the form via AJAX Form using jquery like this

```
var options = {
            target:        '.ajaxMessage',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
           // beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
            dataType: 'json',  // pre-submit callback 
            success:     function(data){ myResponse(data)},

            cache: false,
            delegation: true,
            type: 'POST'   }; 

            $(".r_form").ajaxForm(options);
```

Everything is working fine but after success i want to append the row to  closest table in which form was submitted.

I am not sure what does `this` points to when i use in myresponse() function after success

Comment: `this` would refer to the ajax response, aka `data` in this case. Do you have this code in a click event?

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Comment: Check this fiddle console in [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/74HKn/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the following markup:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form class="r_form" method="post" action="...">
                <input type="submit"/>
            </form>
            <div class="ajaxMessage"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form class="r_form" method="post" action="...">
                <input type="submit"/>
            </form>
            <div class="ajaxMessage"></div>
        </td>
        ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

you could do this in your document.ready handler to AJAXify those forms:

```
var options = {
    success: function(data, statusText, xhr, form) {
        var ajaxMessage = $(form).closest('td').find('.ajaxMessage');
        ajaxMessage.html(data);
    }
}; 
$('.r_form').ajaxForm(options);
```

As explained in the [documentation](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object) the fourth argument of the `success` callback will represent the corresponding form DOM element and it could be used to find the containing `<td>` (or `<tr>` depending on where is the ajaxMessage element located) and from there find the `.ajaxMessage` div to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Some psuedo-code that should get you on the right track:

```
$('input:submit').click(function(e){

    var $target = $(e.target);

    var $closestTable = $target.closest('table');

    $closestTable.append('<tr><td>blah</td></tr>'); //this line could be added to the success handler
});
```

Answer (score 0):

"The this reference within all callbacks is the object in the context option passed to $.ajax in the settings; if context is not specified, this is a reference to the Ajax settings themselves."

From: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Seems like you can pass the object which triggered the ajax call through `context`, and then use `.closest('table')` to get to the table you want.